# Why wont the integers print from a file in C

Tags: c, file

I've written a simple program in C to read integers from a file, and print out the integers to `stdout`. The code compiles, but will not print out the integers I wrote in a different file. Here is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "r");
    int x = 0;
    int nums[1024];
    int num;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) == 1) {
        nums[x] = num;
        x++;
    }

    printf("Here are your numbers");

    int i = 0;

    while (nums[i] != '\0') {
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

I'm only trying to print the integers written in `fp`

Comment: done any basic debugging, like seeing if your file actually opened properly? that your first while() loop actually found something to read? Note that `argv[0]` is the name of the program itself, so you're tryign to read your binary executable, not a command line argument.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the program name. And check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: The code you posted has a typo, `int nums`.

Comment: Did u try to print the numbers in the first while to see if you read them properly?

Comment: @MarcB that is what i am trying to achieve with this code. It was just a test to make sure that i am reading the file correctly by printing out what is written.

Comment: but you said "different file", so ... exactly what are you trying to accomplish? if the numbers you want to print are in a different file, then you should be fopen/fread THAT file, not the file your program lives in. and note that a binary executable is not going to be just "numbers". e.g. a windows .exe starts with the letters `MZ`, which is NOT going to get captured by your fscanf.

Comment: `while(nums[i] != '\0'){` --> `for (i=0; i<x; i++){`

Comment: How is it posible tto post code that compiles, but has typos/bugs like that?  It's almost like you just typed it in from somewhere and did not try to compile, link, test or debug at all before posting here.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `argv[0]` is the program name. I think you mean `argv[1]`, which is the first command line argument, not including the program name. Then, check the return value of `fopen`. If it is `NULL`, the file could not be opened. The revised code is

```
int main(char *argv[], int argc)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL) {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &i) > 0)
            printf("%d\n", i);
    } else /* could not open file; print reason */
        perror("fopen");

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: `fclose(NULL)` is not well defined.  Best to have in `if()` block.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a number of problems.  First the typo: `nums` is declared but the variable is `num`.

`argv[0]` is not the first argument to the program, it is the name of the program (the first argument to the `execv` call which spawned the program).  The first argument to the program is `argv[1]`.  You must check that `argv[1]` exists and that the file opened successfully.

```
  if( argc <= 1 ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
      return -1;
  }

  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if( fp == NULL ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s for reading\n", argv[1]);
      return -1;
  }
```

Then there's the problem of how you're determining how many numbers there are in the array.  The technique you used would work for a null terminated string (a character array), or an array of pointers, but for an array of integers `nums[i] != '\0'` is the same as `nums[i] != 0` and you may well read in the number zero.  So you can't use this boundary technique on an array of integers.  (You also forgot to set the boundary at the end of reading in numbers)

Instead you already have `x` keeping track of how many numbers you've read in.  Use that.  I've renamed it to the more descriptive `num_nums`. I've also used a `for` loop to make loops with an incrementing counter clearer.

```
  int num_nums = 0;
  int nums[1024];
  int num;

  for( num_nums = 0; fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) == 1; num_nums++ ) {
    nums[num_nums] = num;
  }

  printf("Here are your numbers.\n");

  for( int i = 0; i < num_nums; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
  }
```

The final problem is the use of a fixed size array to process input.  Fixed size buffers and input are a security hole waiting to happen.  You should either limit your input to the size of the buffer (ie. 1024 numbers), or even better, use an array which grows automatically.  This type of array is usually a struct which also keeps track of its size for you.

Rather than implementing one, I'd encourage you to use one of the many libraries out there which provide improved data structures such as [Gnome Lib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html).

Comment: For completeness, you should prevent buffer overflow in `nums[]` by stopping the scan once `1024` numbers have been parsed.

Comment: @chqrlie I'd rather encourage the use of [dynamic arrays](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html) than have arbitrary limits.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @stackptr said [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164668/434551) ...

```
while(nums[i] != '\0'){
```

is not the correct method to loop over the numbers read from the file. The elements of `nums` are uninitialized beyond what was read from the disk. Hence, comparing their values to `'\0'` is cause for undefined behavior.

You can use:

```
// x is the number of ints read into nums.
for ( i = 0; i < x; ++i )
{
   printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to read the executable itself by using `argv[0]`. Although there is nothing wrong in it, but the starting of the file does not match what the `"%d"` specifier expects, therefore the loop will terminate as you have a condition that it must read one entry in every iteration until it cannot read any. Therefore `x` will be `'\0'`.
2. Even if you have used `argv[1]` and passed in some file containing for example, `1 2 3` in it, this would be a disaster. This is because you are printing from the array `nums` until its `i`th entry is not `'\0'`. You have never set `nums` to have `'\0'`, and `nums` is an automatic (local) variable. Therefore your program will have undefined behaviour. To understand what I am telling, try initializing all the elements of `nums` to, say, `5`, and run the program with a file containing the example above. Therefore change the loop to be `while (i < x) { /* print  your nums[i] and increment i */ }`.